# Is it possible to find and replace key without using pop() in python?

Tags: python, replace, dictionary-comprehension

I've my dictionary elements in dic_name. var c has the key value to find in dic_name and var d is the new key to replace c.

```
dic_name[d]=dic_name.pop(c)
```

I've got the following output.

```
Enter the keyname you want to replace: e
Enter the new keyname value: z
ORIGINAL DICTIONARY {'q': '1', 'w': '2', 'e': '8', 'r': '4', 't': '5'}
NEW DICTIONARY {'q': '1', 'w': '2', 'r': '4', 't': '5', 'z': '8'}
```

Suppose if the key is not found, then it will generate key error. For that reason i've used the following code:

```
dic_name[d]=dic_name.pop(c,None)
```

But it creates new key with value as "None".

```
enter the keyname you want to replace: e
enter the new keyname value: r
ORIGINAL DICTIONARY {'q': '1', 'w': '2'}
NEW DICTIONARY {'q': '1', 'w': '2', 'r': None}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more clear on what you're trying to achieve here. Assuming that you want to ignore and do nothing if the key is not found, you can just do:

```
if c in dic_name:
     dic_name[d] =dic_name.pop(c)
```

Comment: i tried that only. but i wanna display, if the key is not present.

Comment: @SHENBGABHARATHAPRIYA: so use `if c not in dic_name: dic_name[d] = some_value`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dict comprehension to create new dict and append replaced value on new dict

```
replace = 'e'
replace_with = 'z'
old_dict = {'q': '1', 'w': '2', 'e': '8', 'r': '4', 't': '5'}
new_dict = {i:j for i,j in old_dict.items() if i != replace}
new_dict[replace_with]=old_dict[replace]
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `pop` for this purpose. Simply handle the key not found condition:

```
try:
    dic_name[d] = dic_name.pop(c)
except KeyError:
    pass
```